# React-three-fiber adding Object3d group

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to implement a library that returns an Object3d group into r3f, How do I get it to display the object3d group in react-three-fiber?

I think it needs to be reparented to Scene and  doesn't seem to work? I just need the equivalent of scene.add(terrain)[three.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPJdI.png) [what it returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndVtB.png) [trying <primitive object={terrain}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaHYy.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)